# How do I prove that $\Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n~~i.o.)=0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

I have the following problem:

> We have given a probability space $(\Omega, F,\Bbb{P})$ and $X_i:\Omega \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ an i.i.d. sequence of random variables. We assume that there is a r.v. $Y$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)}{n}=Y(\omega)$$ I need to show that $$\Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n~~ i.o.)=0$$

I somehow thought about using B.C. lemma, but I don't see how. Because in part b) of the exercise I need to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n|)<\infty$, and thus I don't think B.C. is used, since for this we should know from the beginning that the sum is finite. Therefore I wanted to ask if someone can help me with other ideas. Because also the use of the Law of large numbers does not work since I don't know that $X_i$ is in $L^1$ this I need to deduce in part c) of the exercise.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @OliverDiaz The problem is that we haven't seen this law. I also saw a solution here bet they use this law and we haven't had it

Comment: @OliverDiaz But then I need that they are i.i.d. right? And I also don't know this

Comment: well, you assume in your posting i.i.d. At this point I ran out of ideas. It seems that a trick will, which I can't see now, will make things fit the paradigm of Borel Cantelli.

Comment: @OliverDiaz sorry there was a typo in my last comment I wanted to write that for the Law of large numbers I need $X_i$ in $L^1$ and that's not known right?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, integrability follows from Kolmogorov-Marcienkiewics-Zygmunf theorem if $Y$ is finite a.s. In which case $Y=E[X_1]$ a.s.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Hmm we also haven't had this one sorry. And we need to deduce that $Y=E(X_1)$ in part d) of the exercise

Comment: Just a guess, but I think the key is that the limit $Y(\omega)$ exists everywhere.

Comment: @copper.hat hmm okey sorry at the moment I'm really lost

Comment: Well, I was not quite correct. Everywhere should be as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, one should not use Borel-Cantelli here. Write $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. (As usual in probability theory,  we suppress the argument $\omega$.) The hypothesis is
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{n}=Y \quad (*) \,.$$
Rewriting this with the index $n-1$ replacing $n$ gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1}=Y  \,.$$
Multiplying this by $ (n-1)/n$ gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_{n-1}}{n}=Y    \,.$$
Subtracting this from (*), we obtain
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_n}{n}=0  \,,$$
which implies
$$\Bbb{P}(|X_n|>n~~ i.o.)=0 \,,$$
by the definition of convergence.

Comment: oh wow perfect thanks!

Comment: Good to see that a Mathematician of your Caliber is active at MSE.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $A:=\lim_n\frac{1}{n}S_n$
converges $\Pr$--a.s. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{X_n}{n}=\frac{S_n}{n}-
\Big(\frac{n-1}{n}\Big)\frac{S_{n-1}}{(n-1)}\rightarrow0
\end{align}
Consequently, $\Pr[|X_n|>n,\,\text{i.o}]=0$.

Bonus: By the reversed
Borel--Cantelli lemma and Fubini's theorem
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|X_1|]=\int^\infty_0\Pr[|X_1|>t]\,dt\leq
1+\sum_{n\geq1}\Pr[|X_1|>n]<\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: sorry could you maybe give some more information about your bonus part? I somehow don't get the steps between

Comment: @aprozz: The reverse Borel-Cantelly lemma states that if $(A_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ are independent events and $\sum_nP[A_n]=\infty$, then $P[A_n\,\text{i.o}]=1$. In your problem, since There events $A_n=\{|X_n|>n\}$ are independent and $P[A_n\, \text{i.o}]=0$, then one must have that $\sum_nP[A_n]<\infty$. Notice that $P[A_n]=P[|X_n|>n]=P[|X_1|>n]$ since the $X$s are i.i.d.

Comment: !Aha, I see perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P[|X_n|>n \text{ io.}] > 0$. There is some $\omega$ and a subsequence such that $|X_{n_k}(\omega)| > n_k$ for all $k$.

Let $S_n = X_1+\cdots X_n$, then ${S_n(\omega) \over n} \to Y(\omega)$ and so ${| {S_n(\omega) \over n} - {S_{n-1}(\omega) \over n-1} | } \to 0$.

\begin{eqnarray}
| {S_n(\omega) \over n} - {S_{n-1}(\omega) \over n-1} | &=& | { (n-1) S_n(\omega)- n S_{n-1}(\omega) \over n (n-1)} | \\
&=& | { n( S_n(\omega)- S_{n-1}(\omega)) - S_n(\omega) \over n (n-1)} | \\
&=& | { n X_n(\omega) - S_n(\omega) \over n (n-1)} | \\
&\ge& {n \over n-1}| { X_n(\omega)\over n} | -| { S_n(\omega) \over n (n-1)} |
\end{eqnarray}
This gives
$\limsup _n | {S_n(\omega) \over n} - {S_{n-1}(\omega) \over n-1} | \ge 1$, which is a contradiction.